# Assigning mean value calculated for one group to the rows of another group

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I have the following problem:
I have data like this:

```
tribble(~label_a, ~label_b, ~value,
    "a", "x", 1,
    "a", "x", 3,
    "a", "y", 6,
    "a", "y", 8,
    "b", "x", 10,
    "b", "x", 30,
    "b", "y", 60,
    "b", "y", 80,
    )
```

I would like (using Dplyr) to group it by label_a, then by label_b, calculate mean value but only for groups where label_b is equal to "x", use this mean value for all rows in label_a groups as a new column to obtain something like this:

```
label_a | label_b | value | x_mean
----------------------------------
a       | x       | 1     | 2
a       | x       | 3     | 2
a       | y       | 6     | 2
a       | y       | 8     | 2
b       | x       | 10    | 20
b       | x       | 30    | 20
b       | y       | 60    | 20
b       | y       | 80    | 20
```

But i have no idea how to do this. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you provide data in an R-friendly format? Perhaps either `data.frame(...)` or `dput(x)` would be the clearest. Thanks!

Comment: I'm new here and I'm still learning how to use the interface. I have edited my question to be more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two ways of doing this: an easy way that gets much harder if you have or will get more levels with the labels, and one that is a little more code but might be more robust to larger data.

### 1: Easy but scales poorly

```r
x %>%
  group_by(label_a) %>%
  mutate(x_mean = mean(if_else(label_b == "x", value, value[NA]), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 8 x 4
#   label_a label_b value x_mean
#   <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 a       x           1      2
# 2 a       x           3      2
# 3 a       y           6      2
# 4 a       y           8      2
# 5 b       x          10     20
# 6 b       x          30     20
# 7 b       y          60     20
# 8 b       y          80     20
```

The crux of this one is that we take the mean only of the `"x"` values, omitting the rest. The use of `if_else` gives a vectorized if/then-like statement, and the use of `value[NA]` is to guarantee that we get the "right kind of `NA`" (there are more than a few different `NA`s in R).

### 2: More robust

```r
x %>%
  filter(label_b == "x") %>%
  group_by(label_a) %>%
  summarize(x_mean = mean(value)) %>%
  left_join(x, ., by = "label_a") %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 8 x 4
#   label_a label_b value x_mean
#   <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 a       x           1      2
# 2 a       x           3      2
# 3 a       y           6      2
# 4 a       y           8      2
# 5 b       x          10     20
# 6 b       x          30     20
# 7 b       y          60     20
# 8 b       y          80     20
```

This one works by first creating a summary table:

```r
x %>%
  filter(label_b == "x") %>%
  group_by(label_a) %>%
  summarize(x_mean = mean(value))
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   label_a x_mean
#   <chr>    <dbl>
# 1 a            2
# 2 b           20
```

and then *merging* it back into the original frame. In base R, we would use `merge`, in SQL and `dplyr`-speak, we use a `join` operator. (There are several examples of multiple join-like operations here: [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871), I encourage you to take a look and try some of the samples to see what is going on.)

It's not uncommon for the intermediate summary table to be stored in another variable and `join`ed with the original frame in a different pipe. In the case here, I just did something like a "self-`join`" (though it is far from "itself" by the time we get to the join operation).

Comment: Thank you mister for your comprehensive answer

Comment: Your first solution also works if you do this: ```mutate(x_mean = mean(value[label_b == 'x']))```.  Not sure if that would be robust enough.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone looks for the `data.table` solution:

```
dt[, x_mean := mean(value[label_b == 'x'])
   , by = label_a]
```